# Can the particle "no" の be used at the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: grammar, usage

In the sentence

> Watashi no hon.

Can the owner be omitted?

> No hon.

Answer (score 9):

Nope.

One minor exception would be “finishing someone else’s sentence”, like

> 「やったのは誰？太郎？」
>   「…の弟、ね」
>   “ Who did it? Taro?”
>   “...’s little brother, actually.”

But this is really only possible when the last word of the person you are speaking to is the head of your sentence. It feels less like a grammatical thing and more like a conversational trick.

Comment: I never considered sentence continuation.  That's pretty much the only case you'd encounter it.

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, the answer is no.  However, you *could* leave the **subject** off the end of the sentence *if* it's well understood within the sentence context.

> ×　わたしの（です）。　→　No context
>
> ○　A:　誰の本ですか？
>      　B:　わたしの（です）　→　It's understood that the book is the subject

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no.

While you can leave off the subject of a sentence if it is understood, the same cannot be done this grammatical structure.

の is a particle that is formed by the following structures

> Noun の Noun
>  (watashi no hon)

or

> Noun (particle) の Noun 
> (Amerika kara no hon).

Often, you will see it in connection with noun phrases, which makes the usage very versatile, but not in the way you ask.